# database with mutiple itmes in a column

Tags: database

I have a newb database question. I have a list of publications, and I want to create a database. I had been thinking I would do:

UID, Author, URL, Title, Publication, start page, end page, volume, year

for the columns in my database,but then I saw that some publications have numerous authors, and I'm not sure how to handle that. What should I do?

Comment: What kind of DB? SQL? MySQL? NoSQL??? Please provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal action would be to create a separate table for the authors and then create a separate table, where you store the primary keys for author and books, take a look at the following example (Fourth Normal Form):

[Database Normalization](https://blog.udemy.com/normalization-in-database-with-example/)